# Is there a way to find the probability p with R for pbinom

Tags: r, probability, equation, binomial-cdf

I think this is a rather common problem, but I could not find a solution.

I want to solve the following equation:
pbinom(18,25,p)=0.05.

Is there a way to find the unknown p with the program R?

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Garondal, welcome to Stackoverflow! With the the way that you ask your question now, I am not exactly sure what it is that you want. However, the following website shows how to work with `pbinom` in R so might be useful to you: 

http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/probability-distributions/binomial-distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root finding:

```
print(
  res <- uniroot(function(p) pbinom(18,25,p) - 0.05, c(0, 1), 
          tol = .Machine$double.eps)
)

pbinom(18,25,res$root)
#[1] 0.05
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force :

```
p = 0.0001 # starting point
while (abs(pbinom(18,25,p) -  0.05) > 0.001) p <- p + 0.001
```

This code evaluates the pdf for different values of p until you are "close enough" to 0.05. Here "close enough" means at the 0.001 range.

> ```
> > p
> [1] 0.8601
> > pbinom(18,25,0.8601)
> [1] 0.05070763
> ```

Comment: Why seek an approximate solution when @Roland's exact solution is simple and (probably) quicker?

Comment: @Limey My solution is approximate (as all numeric solutions must be). It is basically the same approach as Trusky's but using a better algorithm.

Comment: Indeed, the main difference is the tolerance set at `.Machine$double.eps` and the high quality algorithm behind `uniroot`. Roland's answers is perfect, for sure.

Comment: Actually, the answer is nice if somebody wants to see how the while-loop works.